# How to set image from url to button background?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I would like to set the background image for a button to an image I have from a URL; but the following code does not work:

```
var button = new Button();
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-folder-128.png", UriKind.Absolute));                
button = image;
```

Specifically "`button = image`" doesn't work, because Button isn't Image type.

How should I set an image to be the background image of a button?

Comment: Button should have a property called `BackgroundImage` or somesuch. Of course you shouldn't set an image to be a button; it's not, it's an image.

Comment: Button have not property like this. I can't see any property like image or somethink.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Topic to close. I found a solution. Thank you for help.

Comment: @marcin1102 We don't close questions because they're answered. Mark the answer that solved your problem if one has.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using `WebClient` to first download the image locally before displaying it in the `Button` control

```
using (WebClient c = new WebClient())
{
    c.DownloadFile("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-folder-128.png", "D:/image.png");
}
button.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/image.png");
```

Where `D:/image.png` is the location you would like to save your image to

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got a solution.

```
            var button = new Button();
            var image = new ImageBrush();
            image.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));         
            button.Background = image;
```